# Poem (random words) generator: How can I get each paragraph to display a different set of random words?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, random

I'm working on a little practice project that should generate poems. I created a couple of arrays full of different types of words, which I'm then grabbing randomly and adding into paragraphs. It's working, but not how I would like it to.

Since each "phrase" variable is pulling from the same set of randomly selected words, the poems are all repetitive. Whatever random noun is selected will appear in each noun slot, each random verb appears in every verb slot etc.

**What I want to happen is: each slot will generate a different random word from the array. If a two of the same words are coincidentally selected at random, that's ok.**

For now each type of words selected randomly once, and repeated along all the sentences.

What can I do for i't will selected randomly any time?

Here's the code.

```js
  

     
    
    
    
    function makeAPoem() {
      var nouns = ["cat", "crow", "snow", "home", "boy", "raven", "tree", "moon", "night", "day", "winter", "heart", "angel", "madam", "darkness", "chamber", "lady", "bird", "person", "eye", "darkness", "air"];
      var verbs = ["ran", "felt", "fell", "focused", "looked", "stared", "sat", "sighed", "blew", "whimpered", "embraced", "hugged"];
      var articles = ["a", "the"];
      var adjectives = ["shiny", "sad", "cold", "cheerfully", "sweet", "evil"];
      var pronouns = ["I", "we", "you", "they", "she", "it", "he"];
    
    
      var randNoun = Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length);
      var randVerb = Math.floor(Math.random() * verbs.length);
      var randArticle = Math.floor(Math.random() * articles.length);
      var randAdjective = Math.floor(Math.random() * adjectives.length);
      var randPronoun = Math.floor(Math.random() * pronouns.length);
    
      var phrase1 = pronouns[randPronoun] + " " + verbs[randVerb] + " " + adjectives[randAdjective];
      var phrase2 = articles[randArticle] + " " + nouns[randNoun] + " " + verbs[randVerb] + " " + adjectives[randAdjective];
      var phrase3 = pronouns[randPronoun] + " " + verbs[randVerb] + ". " + articles[randArticle] + " " + nouns[randNoun] + " " +  verbs[randVerb] + " " + adjectives[randAdjective];
      var phrase4 = articles[randArticle] + " " + nouns[randNoun] + " " + verbs[randVerb] + " " + adjectives[randAdjective];
      var phrase5 = pronouns[randPronoun] + " " + verbs[randVerb];
    
      document.getElementsByClassName('poem')[0].innerHTML = phrase1;
      document.getElementsByClassName('poem')[1].innerHTML = phrase2;
      document.getElementsByClassName('poem')[2].innerHTML = phrase3;
      document.getElementsByClassName('poem')[3].innerHTML = phrase4;
      document.getElementsByClassName('poem')[4].innerHTML = phrase5;
    }
```

```html
 

    <div id="poemBox">
    <div id="edgar">
      <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/52/76652-050-F4A6B093/Edgar-Allan-Poe.jpg" width="150px" alt="avatar">
      <p>Press the button below for a poem from Poe.</p>
      <button onclick="makeAPoem()">Go</button>
    </div>
    <div id="poetry">
      <p class="poem"></p>
      <p class="poem"></p>
      <p class="poem"></p>
      <p class="poem"></p>
      <p class="poem"></p>
    </div>
```

In the [Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wOAj.png) here, every occurrence of a random adjective is using "sweet". Every random verb is "focused" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you generate any word type just once.
Just generate the randoms before any phase

```js
function makeAPoem() {
  var nouns = ["cat", "crow", "snow", "home", "boy", "raven", "tree", "moon", "night", "day", "winter", "heart", "angel", "madam", "darkness", "chamber", "lady", "bird", "person", "eye", "darkness", "air"];
  var verbs = ["ran", "felt", "fell", "focused", "looked", "stared", "sat", "sighed", "blew", "whimpered", "embraced", "hugged"];
  var articles = ["a", "the"];
  var adjectives = ["shiny", "sad", "cold", "cheerfully", "sweet", "evil"];
  var pronouns = ["I", "we", "you", "they", "she", "it", "he"];

  function randNoun(){return nouns[Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length)]}
  function randVerb(){return verbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * verbs.length)]}
  function randArticle(){return articles[Math.floor(Math.random() * articles.length)]}
  function randAdjective(){return adjectives[Math.floor(Math.random() * adjectives.length)]}
  function randPronoun(){return pronouns[Math.floor(Math.random() * pronouns.length)]}

  var phrase1 = randPronoun() + " " + randVerb() + " " + randAdjective();
  var phrase2 = randArticle() + " " + randNoun() + " " + randVerb() + " " + randAdjective();
  var phrase3 = randPronoun() + " " + randVerb() + ". " + randArticle() + " " + randNoun() + " " +  randVerb() + " " + randAdjective();
  var phrase4 = randArticle() + " " + randNoun() + " " + randVerb() + " " + randAdjective();
  var phrase5 = randPronoun() + " " + randVerb();

  document.getElementsByClassName('poem')[0].innerHTML = phrase1;
  document.getElementsByClassName('poem')[1].innerHTML = phrase2;
  document.getElementsByClassName('poem')[2].innerHTML = phrase3;
  document.getElementsByClassName('poem')[3].innerHTML = phrase4;
  document.getElementsByClassName('poem')[4].innerHTML = phrase5;
}
```

```html
<div id="poemBox">
<div id="edgar">
  <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/52/76652-050-F4A6B093/Edgar-Allan-Poe.jpg" width="150px" alt="avatar">
  <p>Press the button below for a poem from Poe.</p>
  <button onclick="makeAPoem()">Go</button>
</div>
<div id="poetry">
  <p class="poem"></p>
  <p class="poem"></p>
  <p class="poem"></p>
  <p class="poem"></p>
  <p class="poem"></p>
</div>
```